# Monaca+Angular+OnsenUIで、input が type="password"のとき、jQueryで値が正しく取得できない

Tags: monaca, jquery, onsen-ui, angularjs

Angular+OnsenUIで、input が `type="password"`のとき、以下のいずれの方法でも最後の文字が、パスワードの隠し文字に化けます。

```
jQuery("#passwordInput").val()
jQuery("#passwordInput").prop('value')
```

具体的なHTML

```
<input type="password" id="passwordInput" class="topInputBox"/>
```

入力内容：asdfghjk
取得される値：asdfghj●

取得方法、なにか間違えていますでしょうか？
CLI Ver 5.2.0、デバッガAndroid版最新です。

Comment: 私の環境では上記現象は発生しませんでした。サンプルでも何でもよいので、実際に現象が再現できるコードを載せていただかないと解決は難しいと思いますが。